# SQL "replace" id with customer epoch

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small customer database including the table below:

```
Person_ID | Order_ID
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 3
2 | 4
```

I want to create a view, which starts the Order_ID for each customer separately for creating epochs, like:

```
Person_ID | Order_ID | Epoch_ID
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 2 | 2
2 | 3 | 1
2 | 4 | 1
```

Anyone an idea how I can do that? I only know how to do it in Prolog.

Comment: what BDMS are you using?

Comment: Prolog or SQL as your Question is tagged? ;-) However, if queueing against a Microsoft SQL Server, the DENSE_RANK will be your tool of choice: SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY person_id, order_id) AS epoch_id FROM TestTable

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I am using mysql - phpMyAdmin...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will work.

```
SELECT Person_ID, 
       Order_ID,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY Person_ID,Order_ID) AS  Epoch_ID
```

Output slightly changed.

```
Person_ID | Order_ID | Epoch_ID
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 2 | 2
2 | 3 | 1
2 | 4 | 2
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks again. In the end, i did it this way: